# Генератор имен на php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, как на php сделать генератор имен. Генерация должна быть по определенному принципу:
согласная - гласная - двойная согласная - гласная - согласная
Пример:

- tettet
- tettes
- teppet
- seppet
- teddet
- tesset
- pesses
- kemmet
- teffet
- tehhet
- tekkeb
- tennes
- temmet
- tebbet
- pennet
- memmet

По центру всегда должны быть 2 повторные согласные (tt,pp,ss,dd,ff,hh,kk,zz,vv,bb,nn,mm).
В начале и конце любая согласная t,p,s,d,f,h,k,z,v,b,n,m
На месте гласных только следующие буквы: e, i, o, a, u

Comment: делайте два массива, гласных и согласных, с помощью [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-rand.php) выбирайте случайные значения на первые две буквы, потом выводите два раза одну и туже согласную, а потом опять из массива гласных и согласных....

Comment: Нужен не совсем рандом, а вывод всех возможных значений, которое можно составить из этих букв.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю сделать так:

```
$array_a = array(e,y,u,i,o,a);
$array_b = array(q,w,r,t,p,s,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,z,x,c,v,b,n,m);

foreach($array_b as $b1){
    foreach($array_a as $a1){
        foreach($array_b as $b2){
            foreach($array_a as $a2){
                foreach($array_b as $b3){
                    echo $b1.$a1.$b2.$b2.$a2.$b3."\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```